# Content isn't visible on the website but it's added in ACP

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm new to TYPO3. I came across a small problem - I've added content blocks in ACP (=admin control panel) but they're not visible live.

`web_layout.tsconfig`:

```
yellow {
  config {
    backend_layout {
      colCount = 2
      rowCount = 3
      rows {
        1 {
          columns {
            1 {
              colPos = 0
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.0
            }
            2 {
              colPos = 1
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.1
            }
          }
        }
        2 {
          columns {
            3 {
              colPos = 2
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.2
            }
            4 {
              colPos = 3
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.3
            }
          }
        }
        3 {
          columns {
            5 {
              colPos = 4
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.4
            }
            6 {
              colPos = 5
              name = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow.colPos.5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  title = LLL:EXT:site/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:backendLayout.yellow
}
```

I need to make them visible. As you can see in my `web_layout.tsconfig` I have 2 columns and 3 rows but on the website there is visible only first row and first column - without the rest of them.

Where should I change config to allow/show TYPO3 that I want to display all 2 columns and 3 rows?

Comment: What does ACP mean?

Comment: Have you added the "web_layout.tsconfig" file to your Page TS? If yes, is the backend layout visible in the page properties and have you selected your backend layout there?

Comment: ACP admin control panel

Comment: Admin control panel is no word from the TYPO3 world. There is an admin panel but that has nothing to do with backend layouts.

Comment: I selected in `Page > Apperance > Backend Layout`

Comment: So you mean the page properties. Is there the configured backend layout visible?

Comment: @Chris in Extbase Variable Dump in content field I see content only from first row from first column

Comment: Now you are speaking of the frontend. Can you select the backend layout in backend in the page properties. And if yes, then there should be the grid displayed on that page where you can put the content elements in.

Comment: @Chris summing up: 1. I created new page (`Web > Page > New`) then I changed `web_layout.tsconfig` and created layout I want - 2 columns, 3 rows, then I changed in Page properties position `Backend Layout` to target layout and at the end I completed the content. And it doesn't work (isn't visible on website).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a **backend** layout you have not changed the rendering for the frontend.
For the frontent you need to adapt the rendering. best way would be to change it depending on selected backend layout.

Therefore you need to copy the given FLUID templates (Layouts/ Templates/ Partials) into your own extension, modify them and add them to the paths.
More information can be found in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Introduction.html#introduction-to-fluid)